# How to add charm information by ICS import in Office 365 Calendar?

Tags: outlook, office365, icalendar

Is there any way to set "charm" information in .ics file?

[image]

I have read the document [[MS-OXCICAL]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463911(v=exchg.80).aspx), but I didn't find any properties of charm.

Comment: What is "charm"? Color?

Comment: Charm is like category but it is an icon. It seems a special feature which Office 365 supported. I have added the charm screenshot in the question.

Comment: You could set a charm for an event, then send out invitation to e.g. gmail email address, open the attached .ics on gmail and check whether any property that could be related to charm is present.

Comment: @grepfruit 
Thanks for your suggestion. However, there are not any property which is related to charm, and the .ics file which Microsoft server provided can not set the charm information either.